# Using String.toLowerCase() without getting a resolve error, JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a final question on my piece of code. As a last thing i want to build in a function which will ignore the case sensitivity. So "user" and "USER" and "UsEr" should be treated the same way. I have a first idea how to implement such a function. Thats what i tried out:

```
        <% if (name != null) { namecheck = name.toLowerCase(); } 
           else { namecheck = request.getParameter("name"); }
        %>

        <% if (password != null) { passwordcheck = password.toLowerCase(); } 
           else { passwordcheck = request.getParameter("password"); }
        %>
```

Since i must check if it's NULL to avoid an error, it is not so easy to implement.
Now i could found out that my "namecheck" and "passwordcheck" are only avaible in the curled if-brackets. So the compiler gives me a "not resolved" error. I don't know how to fix this problem without writing a huge number of if-else.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">

        <head>
          <title>Practice</title>
        </head>

        <body>

        <h2>Practice</h2>
        <h3>Please enter your name and the password.</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <table>

        <tr><td style="text-align:center">Name</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.name)}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:center">Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.password)}" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        <%-- Testing name and password. --%>
        <% String name = request.getParameter("name");
           String password = request.getParameter("password");
        %>  

        <%-- Trying to use the .toLowerCase(). --%>

        <% if (name != null) { namecheck = name.toLowerCase(); } 
           else { namecheck = request.getParameter("name"); }
        %>

        <% if (password != null) { passwordcheck = password.toLowerCase(); } 
           else { passwordcheck = request.getParameter("password"); }
        %>    


        <% if (namecheck != null && name.equals("user") && passwordcheck != null && password.equals("1234")) 
             {
        %>
               <p>Your Input is correct!</p>
        <%   }

           else
             {
        %>
               <p>Your input is not correct!</p>
        <%   }
        %>

        </body>


        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`String#equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
if (name != null && name.equalsIgnoreCase("user")
    && password != null && password.equalsIgnoreCase("1234")) 
{
    // Pass.
}
```

I keep repeating: JSP is the wrong place for this stuff. I hope it's "just" homework.

Comment: Whooooo boy if you think JSPs are the wrong place for this logic, you would have a heart attack at what I do every day. The company decided long ago that almost all business logic should take place in the JSPs, so they get...pretty big and complex.   EDIT: Unless you mean password and username checking, then I agree.

Comment: @josh: We actually convert existing legacy scriptlet-cluttered JSPs to fullworthy JSF 2.0/Facelets pages. @Ordo: OK, I'll keep this in mind when answering your future questions :) Good luck at your school...

Comment: @josh :it depends,if u use MVC design pattern , so it's not advisable to make any control coding in ur jsp pages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not seeing something else, but I don't see that you ever declared namecheck and passwordCheck as Strings. If you want to keep them available just declare them next to where you 'get' name and pas

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare variables you're using.

Try declaring `namecheck` and `passwordcheck`, for example:

```
 <% String name = request.getParameter("name");
   String password = request.getParameter("password");
   String namecheck = "";
   String passwordcheck = "";
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code using jstl core tag libary.

[API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html)